# Redis-cli - Selecting which instance?

Tags: database, nosql, redis

I'm currently running multiple redis instances on one box. Each have their own config, init.d, and listen on different ports. My application(s) have no problem connecting via the redis clients, but I'd like to be able to connect to each one using redis-cli. I couldn't find any information on $:redis-cli [options] in either the redis-doc or on redis.io. Any ideas?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can specify the server host and port using -h and -p parameters. E.g.:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
```

Comment: `redis-cli --help` shows you what other flags it accepts.

Comment: use `-n1` to specify DB with index of 1, new connections default to 0

Comment: It should be `-n 1`, I guess. With a space,

Answer (score 1):

Try this Redis GUI management tool, it also have console support - http://redisdesktop.com/

[image: redis desktop manager consoles]